# How do I call ChannelFactory<TChannel> dynamically?

Tags: c#, channelfactory

I have to call `ChannelFactory<TChannel>` class. But the code below is for `ChannelFactory` Class. I don't have any idea, how to call `ChannelFactory<TChannel>`. Please suggest how I might call the `ChannelFactory<TChannel>` class.

```
string interfaceName = "Test";  
Type myInterfaceType = Type.GetType(interfaceName);
var factoryType = typeof(ChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(myInterfaceType);
var factoryCtr = factoryType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(BasicHttpBinding), typeof(EndpointAddress) });
ChannelFactory factorry = factoryCtr.Invoke(new object[] { new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(cmbpath.SelectedItem.ToString()) }) as ChannelFactory;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code in a Console App:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ExperimentConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string endPoint = "http://localhost/service.svc";

            string interfaceName = "ExperimentConsoleApp.ITest";
            Type myInterfaceType = Type.GetType(interfaceName);
            var factoryType = typeof(ChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(myInterfaceType);
            ChannelFactory factory = Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType, new object[] { new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(endPoint) }) as ChannelFactory;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    { }
}
```

A few points:

- Use Activator.CreateInstance to create a type trough reflection
- You should fully qualify your interfaceName to make sure reflection can find it
- Decorate your service interface with ServiceContract
- Make sure your endpoint is in a valid format

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have 2 problems here, dynamically creating the ChannelFactory and dynamically invoking it, and Reflection is the solution for both of them.

Both your code and Wouter's code are good at dynamically creating the ChannelFactory object via Reflection, the problem is that as the type is unknown at compile time you can't cast to it, and all you can get is the non generic (non useful) ChannelFactory.

So, to create your concrete Channel and then invoke methods on it, you can go the long way using Reflection again on your own... or let the runtime itself use Reflection on your behalf by means of dynamic. That is, change your last (or Wouter's last) line to:

```
dynamic factory = factoryCtr.Invoke(.....
```

or

```
dynamic factory = Activator.CreateInstance(...
```

with no need to include the "as ChannelFactory" at the end.

and then just use:

```
dynamic channel = factory.CreateChannel();
//and now invoke the methods in your Interface
channel.TestMethod...
```